# USB-C power microcontroller ESP-32-S2 and NeoPixels

Tags: power, esp32, usb-c

I am working on making a custom PCB that powers an ESP32-S2, as well as roughly 40 NeoPixels using a USB-c connector.

I made my first set of boards (ever) and was thrilled the computer recognized it and allowed me to flash firmware and blink an onboard LED. However, I seemed to have some issues with powering the NeoPixels.

On the USB-c I used 5k resistors on each CC pins to get the 5 V, then had a VREG to step the 5 V down to 3.3 V for the board. I thought I might be able to split two of the VDDs pins from USB-c to the VREG and microcontroller and utilize the other two VDDs for pure 5 V to the NeoPixels. I feel like this is probably not the right way and looking for how to split power between the two safely.

What is the proper way to utilize USB-c to accomplish this? I have a picture of the PCB layout, my schematic isn’t on this device, but can upload later to be more helpful. All power probably should’ve been tied together, possibly a VREG on the neopixel side as well, in case I get more than 5 V from a wall charger? Should I have utilized any of the power delivery negotiation to get more amps so NeoPixels get enough current?

I would love any help or advice. I am really enjoying this type of work but definitely have a lot to learn!

[image]

Adding an additional image for the schematic
[image]

Comment: With USB C, connect all VBUS pins together, these pins are provided multiple times as to reduce the resistance of the connection

Comment: First step is to calculate your power requirements, second is to work out how to deliver that much power at the right voltage.

Comment: A lot of things could be better - but is that a 74HC125 or something else than "HC"?

Comment: @Finbarr I think general rule for neopixels is max draw is 60mA x 40leds /1000 which would be 2.4 amps. However, these rarely utilize all LEDs and not typically white. So turn there is just the draw of the esp32 as well

Comment: @Justme is a 74hc125, it’s being used to take the 3.3v signal up to a 5v data signal for neopixels. I think I can use a different chip next go round perhaps because it’s a quad and I only utilize one of the.

Comment: You might only be getting 900mA from your USB-C supply using resistors to activate it. You might need to negotiate a higher voltage and then use a buck converter to step it down to 5V for the neopixels and then 3.3V for the MCU,

Answer (score 2):

At least the 74HC125 can be one reason it does not work.

When powered with 5V supply voltage, HC family chips need more than 3.3V input signal voltage to work reliably, and the ESP32 will only provide 3.3V signal.

Also it seems that power supplies to the 74HC125 are not connected at all - or at least not visible

Edit: OK, power supplies are present in the schematics, they were not visible on PCB layout. But there's no bypass caps on the regulator input VBUS or the 5V nodes. And unused inputs of the HC125 are floating, they should be tied to GND or VCC.

Comment: I added the schematic to show what I currently have in place

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use a 74HCT125 in place of the HC part.

Comment: @Finbarr what is the difference between the HCT and HC? I’m not sure that I’m following your recommendation, sorry.

Comment: @afreeland The difference is that HC won't work as per specifications it has, but HCT will. It will work with 3.3V signal input.

Comment: @Justme are bypass caps different than decoupling caps? There are some decoupling caps I placed closer to the esp32 on pin 2.  So anytime there is voltage coming in I should place some caps to smooth things out.. in my case both for regulated side and unregulated side

Comment: @afreeland Read the regulator datasheet for referene about decoupling / bypass caps - where to place them, distance from chip, suitable value range, and suitable capacitor material.

Comment: HCT is designed to be compatible with old-fashioned TTL devices, and it accepts anything above about 2V as a logic 1.

Comment: @Justme Alright, finally getting a chance to redo this design.  I am only using 1 of the bus buffers and according to the datasheet for 74hct125n I can pull OE high to disable..so I am pulling the 3 unused OEs high.  For all the corresponding pins in KiCad I hooked them to the 'X' in the right toolbar to show not connected.  Is that correct? Or do I really have to label them all GND and pull them down (to not be floating), just felt messy in the schematic.

Answer (score 1):

- Like others have mentioned, you should have your USB-C Pins tied together on your connector. They all share the same exact 5V power rail since they are internally connected, so you wouldn't be doing yourself any favors by splitting them.
- On your schematic and PCB, you should have a 0.1uF Ceramic Cap by your Logic Level shifter, and Cermaic Caps on the Voltage Input and Output of your Linear Regulator (refer to the datasheet for recommended values). These caps should be placed as close to the Vin and Vout pin as possible. Wouldn't be a bad idea to add a 10uF capacitor in between V+ and GND on the USB C connector either.
- I think AdaFruit recommends adding a 300 ohm to 500 ohm resistor in series with the dataline, so I would add that to your Logic Shifter output (1Y).
- On your PCB design, don't use right angle traces when routing. having right angles in your design is bad practice in general, and should just be avoided, if possible.
- Your traces from your 5V output on your USB-C connector to your NeoPixels aren't very thick. Make those traces thicker (at least 30 mils, let say, but you can go bigger) so you're not getting a massive voltage drop on your output to your NeoPixels.

I'm not trying to rip your design apart, I'm just trying to help in the best way possible. :)

Comment: No worries at all, I very much appreciate the detailed feedback! Excited to learn and get better at building circuits in general. Will definitely incorporate these into the next iteration, thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

> I thought I might be able to split two of the VDDs pins from USB-c to
> the VREG and microcontroller and utilize the other two VDDs for pure 5
> V to the NeoPixels. I feel like this is probably not the right way and
> looking for how to split power between the two safely.
>
> What is the proper way to utilize USB-c to accomplish this?

No, it is not a proper way. Per USB Type-C Specifications, release 1.3,

**Table 3-10 USB Full-Featured Type-C Standard Cable Assembly Wiring**
[image]

the cable has only one physical wire for VBUS (and GND), so all four VBUS pins will be connected together inside the plugs, and this arrangement will short all your splits. So you cannot use the standard Type-C cables.